# Tag Cloud based on weighted usaage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to create a weighted usage ranking / popularity query (or batch update, if the query proves to strenuous for real-time use!) but I've been drawing a blank.  Hopefully you'll have a better idea as to how to do this.

I've simplified my database to help illustrate the problem (see diagram, below!)  Basically, when a User selects a specific Blog via a Tag, I add an entry to the TagLog table.  Assume for this example that the collection of Blogs and Tags remain static.  Assuming the above, I'd like to do the following:

- Find the Top 10 Blogs for any given Tag
- Find the Top 10 Blogs for any given Tag and User

The real difficulty comes from the fact that I'd like to weight the results such that more recent TagLog entries have greater significance.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks...

[image: Database Diagram]

Comment: What did you try yet?

Comment: If the runtime of the query is only slightly annoying, you can cache the results in a table along with the time they were updated.  When the tag cloud is needed, check the age of the cached copy.  If it exceeds some limit, e.g. 15 minutes, then update the cache.  That way most users don't have to wait for results, but you don't spend time updating the cache when no one cares.

Comment: How do you want to weight the top 10?

Comment: I have gotten as far as creating the database.  Beyond that, I'm more than a bit at sea.  Some thoughts, though, are that month-old tags should have greater importance than year-old tags.  In terms of the second comment (about caching) is a great idea.  I still need a way to do the weighting, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you headed somewhere useful:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Blogs as Table ( BlogId Int Identity, URL VarChar(256) )
insert into @Blogs ( URL ) values
  ( 'www.google.com' ), ( 'www.java.com' )

declare @Tags as Table ( TagId Int Identity, BlogId Int, Tag VarChar(64) )
insert into @Tags ( BlogId, Tag ) values
  ( 1, 'Not Evil' ), ( 2, 'Buggy' )

declare @TagLog as Table ( TagId Int, UserGuid UniqueIdentifier, Visited DateTime )
insert into @TagLog ( TagId, UserGuid, Visited ) values
  ( 1, NewId(), '20130502' ), ( 1, NewId(), '20130508' ), ( 1, NewId(), '20130515' ),
  ( 2, NewId(), '20130501' ), ( 2, NewId(), '20130508' ), ( 2, NewId(), '20130515' )

declare @Now as DateTime = '20130516' -- Test value.

-- Display all sample data.
select *, DateDiff( day, TL.Visited, @Now ) as Age -- Use appropriate units, e.g. week, minute.
  from @Blogs as B inner join
    @Tags as T on T.BlogId = B.BlogId inner join
    @TagLog as TL on TL.TagId = T.TagId

-- Compute a weight based on age.
--   Use the reciprocal of the age so that newer visits have higher weight.
--   Add 1.0 to avoid divide by zero errors.
select T.TagId, Count( 42 ) as Visits, Sum( 1.0 / ( DateDiff( day, TL.Visited, @Now ) + 1.0 ) ) as AgeWeight
  from @Blogs as B inner join
    @Tags as T on T.BlogId = B.BlogId inner join
    @TagLog as TL on TL.TagId = T.TagId
  group by T.TagId
```

Comment: Excellent!  Exactly what I asked for, so thank you.  In exploring things further, I should note that I came across the Stack Exchange Data Explorer which had lots of "popularity" queries.  I'm downloading a huge torrent of data to give it a try(http://data.stackexchange.com/skeptics/query/109257/popular-posts-type-a-vs-type-b).  Again, thank you for you prompt and useful answer